Weak Large Deviation Principle
I am reading Large Deviations Techniques and Applications by Amir Dembo and Ofer Zeitouni. I came across this example and I am confused about how the family of probability measures satisfies the Weak Large Deviation Principle with the given good rate function.
Definition: A rate function is $I$ is a lower-semicontinuous mapping $I:X\rightarrow [0, \infty]$.
For all $\alpha\in[0,\infty)$, the level set for the rate function is$\phi_I(\alpha)=\{x:I(x)\leq \alpha\}$.
A good rate function is a rate function for which all the level sets are compact subsets of $X$.
A family of probability measures $\{\mu_\epsilon\}$ is said to satisfies the weak LDP with the rate function I if for every $\alpha<\infty$ and every compact subset $\Gamma$ of the complement of the level set, $\limsup_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \epsilon \text{log}\mu_\epsilon(\Gamma)\leq -\alpha$, and the lower bound in Large Deviation Principle holds.
Then the book give an example that satisfies the weak LDP but not the full LDP:

So if we pick the $\Gamma=\{1/\epsilon\}$ (which is compact with the Euclidean topology). Then the $\limsup_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \epsilon \text{log}\mu_\epsilon(\{1/\epsilon\})=0$, because the measure degenerates at $1/\epsilon$, the measure of the set will be 1 and $\text{log}1=0$. But then it would not be less than any $\alpha>0$.
This might be a very simple question but this example really confuses me. Any insights or explanation will be appreciated! :)

Your $\Gamma = {1/\varepsilon}$ is varying with $\varepsilon$. The weak LDP is effectively saying: fix a $\alpha,$ and a compact $\Gamma \subset \phi_I(\alpha)^c$, and study the limit behaviour of $\varepsilon \log \mu_\varepsilon(\Gamma)$. In particular, the condition is not required to hold for $\Gamma$ that vary with $\varepsilon$.

So, you could study, e.g., $\Gamma = {1/\varepsilon_0}$ for some constant $\varepsilon_0$. In this case, for small enough $\varepsilon,$ $\mu_\varepsilon({1/\varepsilon_0}) = 0,$ making the limit $-\infty$, which is of course $< - \alpha$ for any $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$. We can also see the difference b/w strong and weak LDP here: strong LDP requires that the same conclusion holds for all closed $\Gamma$, but it obviously fails for $\Gamma = \mathbb{R} = \phi_I(\alpha)^c$ .

@stochasticboy321 Thank you!! This is very helpful. Also this reminds me of a question about notation. Does $\mu_\epsilon$ generally mean the measures decrease as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$?

Well, no, it's just an indexed family of measures. Usually this will be a sequence, for example, the measure induced on some value (like a mean) by drawing $n$ iid copies of a random variable yields such a sequence $\mu_n$. If a LDP is satisfied, then we conclude that for $\Gamma$ in a level-set-complement of $\phi_I$ satisfy $\mu_\varepsilon(\Gamma) \le \exp( - \varepsilon(\alpha + \delta)) $ for large $\varepsilon$ and any $\delta > 0,$ so in that case, and that case alone, the $\mu_\varepsilon(\Gamma)$ do tend to decrease.

@stochasticboy321 Thanks! This becomes so much clear to me! But I am also curious why we want to consider sets that are in the complement of level set? I think it intuitively represents events that are relatively unlikely but I am in general not too sure how to understand this.

First - sorry, I made a typo in the above: in the notation you have it should be $\mu_\varepsilon(\Gamma) \le \exp( - (\alpha + \delta)/\varepsilon),$ with this vanishing for small $\varepsilon.$ The connection to iid stuff would be by taking $\varepsilon = 1/n$ or something like that (so, $\mu_1, \mu_{1/2}, \cdots$).
As for why completement, this is equivalent to saying that if $\Gamma \subset {x : I(x) > \alpha}$, you could just redefine things this way. I think usually it's stated in the form you have for some technical reasons to do with semicontinuity, but its not too important.

I'd say read on even if you don't understand the precise motivation behind all the technical things - you'll probably get to see the issues and reasons better after you have more experience with how these things are used (since, of course, in writing, there is feedback b/w definitions and applications, and things end up converging somewhere that is most convenient from both aspects, but it's not obvious a priori that this is a good compromise).

@stochasticboy321 Thank you for the suggestions! It really helps clear up some of my questions about how to read materials.
